# Can we better organize Broadcom questions?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, canonical-questions

I would suggest if we can have one question for each of the Broadcom chipsets, with one answer covering each of the release. So, we would have one question about Broadcom BCM4313 (and other chipsets) and multiple answers with each of them targeting one release version each.

The main reason behind the idea is - [wireless + bcm4312 closed:0](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=+wireless+%2B+broadcom+%2B+bcm4312+closed%3A0&submit=search) leads to about 40 open questions that are necessarily about the same chipset. If we have had one single question, maintaining the question and the answers would be relatively easier.

Ideally, such questions should be made community wiki in order to let more people help with maintaining the question and update the answer when and where necessary.

Of course, if there arises a need to ask specific question about any of the chipset, I understand such questions should not be blocked.

Any thoughts and opinions on this?

Answer (score 4):

I agree, but not for *each* chipset. Instead, go for the ones that are supported by a b43 variant, the ones supported by the new brcm in-kernel modules and the ones only supported by proprietary wl. Should come down to 5 or 6 "canonical" questions.

See table here: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#Supported_devices

Comment: I concur with this idea.

Comment: Smaller the number of questions, the better. We can look into each of the necessary variants.

Comment: Can you list the 5 or 6 canonical questions you'd like to use so we know what to dupe to what?

Comment: @JorgeCastro: yes, I'll find them (or propose new ones) in a few hours.